# pbcopy adds newline to copied one time password

Tags: macos

I'm setting up a productivity workflow around my password management system, one step of which is grabbing a one time password from a command line utility, and pasting it into a dialog box (unfortunately there's no command line tool).

My command is

```
passwordtool get otp | pbcopy
```

Unfortunately, it appears pbcopy intentionally adds a new line to copied text, so when I paste it in, there's an additional step of back spacing. Not a big deal for me alone, but I want to share out this flow I want to make it as simple for others as possible. Any recommendations on workarounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pbcopy` doesn't add newlines. It must be your `passwordtool` that's doing that. It's customary for command-line tools to add a trailing newline to their `stdout` by default, for various reasons. Tools that need to override that convention usually provide a command-line option to override it, like `echo`'s `-n` option.

For proof, here I'm running `echo` with `-n` to ensure `echo` does NOT add a newline, and piping that into `pbcopy`. Then I'm outputting the clipboard/pasteboard via `pbpaste` and piping it to `hexdump -C` to see exactly what it contains:

```
% echo -n "word" | pbcopy && pbpaste | hexdump -C
00000000  77 6f 72 64                                       |word|
00000004
```

If I take away the `-n` from `echo`, we see what it looks like when we include the newline:

```
% echo "word" | pbcopy && pbpaste | hexdump -C
00000000  77 6f 72 64 0a                                    |word.|
00000005
```

Comment: Interesting. One of the reasons I assumed it did is because I added this at one point `passwordtool get otp | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | pbcopy` but the newline remained. I guess sed also adds a newline?

Comment: Following up, looks like `| tr -d \\n | pbcopy` is the way to go. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @DylanWatt Uhm, I think your `tr` invocation will eat any byte with value 0x0a even if it's in the middle of your OTP data.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the heads up. For my use case, that's fine.